How do I export Google Datastore using a PITR timestamp?
Google Datastore supports "Point-in-time recovery" but the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#export-import only show how to export the data using the firestore command.
The equivalent datastore command of gcloud datastore export does not support the --snapshot-time flag.
The firestore command doesn't work because it expects collection IDs which is not a concept in datastore mode.
So how are we supposed to export from PITR data when using Google Datastore?

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

I have followed the same document and am able to export successfully using the following command.
gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME_PATH] \
    --snapshot-time=[PITR_TIMESTAMP] \
    --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID] \
    --namespace-ids=[NAMESPACE_ID] \
    --database=[DATABASE_NAME]

Here, for collection id you have to use kind name. You can check this document for comparison between Firestore and Datastore.
Also, Make sure you have required permission for Firestore service agent. The Firestore service agent uses the following naming convention:
service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcp-sa-firestore.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Note: Firestore previously used the App Engine default service account instead of the Firestore service agent. If your database still uses the App Engine service account to import or export data, we recommend that you migrate to the service specific Firestore service agent. You can view which account your import and export operations use in the Google Cloud console.

The collection-ids part is pretty confusing. It would be nice if Google would properly add it to the datastore sub-domain as well.

Full name for Datastore is actually Firestore in Datastore mode (see doc). So, gcloud firestore commands work on datastore. If the command explicitly needs to distinguish between firestore in datastore mode and native firestore, it will have an option to specify the type e.g. to create a new database, you specify the type.
In summary, the command you linked to in your question will work for datastore. In fact, the first paragraph on your linked documentation says

This page describes how to export and import Firestore in Datastore mode entities using the managed export and import service.

